# How to replace frameset and frame in html5?

Tags: html, iframe

I am designing a web page. Latest is HTML5 . So I want alternate to frameset. I have frameset as,

```
<frameset rows="75%,25%">
    <frameset cols="20%,80%">

        <frame src=<%=url%> name="left" />
        <frame src=<%=ur%>   name="top" />
    </frameset>
    <frame src=<%=u%> name="bottom"/>
</frameset>
```

I replaced for `<iframe>` as,

`<iframe class="menu" src="newtag.html"  onload="this.width=screen.width;this.height=screen.height;"></iframe>`

here `newtag.html` is the previous html file which used `<frameset>`. My question is, is it good practice? is there any other good way in html5? if it is there please tell me how.? Thank you.

Comment: The question in the title is different from the question in the body, which is about “good practice” and primarily opinion-based. (Besides, there is no change in *browser support* to frames, so why are you rewriting the code?)

Comment: In case anyone else ends up here, this old question needs clarification as its unclear. Most likely you're wanting to know what replaces <frameset> and <frame>s in html5. That would be stuff like <iframe>. Check out ttps://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-html-and-html5. For best practices, you're at the mercy of other opinions or your boss' opinions. Be sure to ask the boss OR the individual can use browser dev tools (F12->application->issues) to find what is/isn't acceptable as a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't a very nice practice to perform...

instead you could try, content place holders as in asp or something like that

Comment: I dont knw asp, can you please any link or example.

Comment: alright, for asp , try this. http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_masterpages.asp

if asp seems hard, you still have <object> in html5, also do all the reloading with ajax